# jquery hide element depending of value of input tag

Tags: jquery

What i want is the `select` div to be displayed only if the value of the input tag next to it is zero.  How do i do this?
Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mdanz/xdFkJ/

```
<style type="text/css">
.select {
overflow:hidden;
display:block;
background-color:red;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var value = $('.row').val();

  if(value!=0) {
  $('.select').hide();  

  }

});
</script>

<div class='select'></div><input type='text' class='row' value='0' />
<div class='select'></div><input type='text' class='row' value='1' />
<div class='select'></div><input type='text' class='row' value='1' />
<div class='select'></div><input type='text' class='row' value='0' />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() { 
  $('input.row').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() != "0") {
      $this.prev().hide();
    } else {
      $this.prev().show();
    }
  });

  $('input.row').trigger('change');
});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfhartsock/xdFkJ/3/.  Note this will also hide the divs when you modify the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this,

```
  $(function() {
    $("input.row").change(function(){
      if($(this).val()=="0"){
         $(this).prev().show();
       }else{
         $(this).prev().hide();
        }

    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use;

```
$(function() {

    $(".select").each(function() {
       var value = $(this).next('.row').val();

       if(value!=0) 
           $(this).hide();

    });
});
```

BTW - you had the fiddle set to mootools.  See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QezaR/):